# iOS6 MKMapView Zoom

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, ios6-maps

I'm trying to get my `MKMapView` to zoom into to an annotation. I've tried all sorts however I remain zoomed out to my `region`.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    NSLog(@"Did add annotations");
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    region.span = span;

    [mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
    [self.spotMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [self.spotMapView regionThatFits:region];
}
```

Which does run, however the map stays zoomed out.

Comment: Why is the region.center being set to the userLocation instead of the annotation (mp)?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not actually sure... I'll have to change that on Monday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `didAddAnnotationViews` to this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    NSLog(@"Did add annotations");
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    [mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:NO];
}
```

Seemed to do the trick, the map now zooms in.